# Wireless Connection Freezes on a Macbook Pro (early 2010 model) with a BCM4322

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro (early 2010 model), and I've been having problems with the network connection periodically stopping.  The wireless network indicator shows that the signal is at full strength (it should be, the router is less that 2 meters from me), but I'm unable to access anything on the network.

None of the other computers are experiencing a problem.

The connection will be fine from 5 minutes to 12 hours, but it will stop.  I'm not even sure how to diagnose the problem to be honest.  While I'm not a beginner, I do struggle when I get into cli.

The wireless connection was fine when I ran OSX and Windows 7 on this machine, but now that I've moved to Ubuntu I've started to have a problem.

Any help, additional information request, or advice on how to diagnose the problem are gratefully received.

I tracked my wireless card version down to: "Broadcom BCM4322", but the drivers appear to be the correct ones, so other than updating (which i've done) I don't know how else to proceed with that line.

Edit:
At the request of @peach heres some more information.

Kernal version:

```
uname -r:
3.0.0-16-generic
```

My connection froze at 13:07, and then 3minutes later, this appeared:

```
tail -f /var/log/message:
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [91969.072690] userif-3: sent link up event.
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.192468] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.198444] cfg80211: World regulatory domai updated:
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.198448] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.198454] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.198459] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.198464] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.198470] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.198475] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar  1 13:10:30 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.233326] userif-3: sent link down event.
Mar  1 13:10:32 rob-laptop kernel: [92447.233335] userif-3: sent link up event.
Mar  1 13:10:32 rob-laptop kernel: [92449.266633] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
Mar  1 13:10:32 rob-laptop kernel: [92449.466506] userif-3: sent link down event.
```

Comment: did you install "Broadcom STA wireless driver" from "Additional Drivers"? btw. which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to see here, seems like someone already reported something similar: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/903437

I'll have a look around when I get back home to see if there's anything else to verify this is actually the same driver problem.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the wireless card itself. My apple care account secured a replacement, but it took 2 weeks to repair.